# How to split or even increase speed downloading for devices?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, download, internet-speed

I have in my network:

1. A PC with 1GBps connection,
2. A laptop for BitTorrnet downloads and media mirror casting using 5ghz,
3. A Home Lab Server with 1GBps connection,
4. 3 phones work in 2.4 Ghz,
5. A tablet use for media surfing using 5ghz.
6. An IPTV case connected using Fast Ethernet

I have Asus RT-AX55 router. And internet speed from IPS to  100Mbps download speed and 100Mbps uploading speed

When I start downloading games from Steam and using the laptop for BitTorrnet downloading, I got the PC have 10mbps speed for downloading but the laptop have 1mpbs. However, if I temporary stopped downloading from Steam, laptop got 10mbps speed downloading.

I tried to use adaptive QoS, bandwidth limiter, now i think to try to use traditional QoS

I'd like to have the pc and the laptop start having equal speed downloading and my server have speed around 15-20mbps, and IPTV case have best quality image.

Comment: From a search:   Performance, It's very much an entry-level Wi-Fi 6 router   .....  You may need a router with faster internal throughput.

Comment: @John, What kind a router is good and why this so bad for these tasks ??

Comment: For my own use I use entry level commercial Cisco routers with near 1 GB/sec throughput.

Comment: @John, so why this is router so bad for home use??? It have also the speed for internal devices 1GB/s

Comment: I am not sure why it slows down other devices. I cannot answer that one.

Comment: One reason would be the 2.4 GHz devices. If you have 2.4 GHz it means you are NOT using WiFi 6 or WiFi 6E

Comment: @Ramhound, but my tablet has support of wifi 6, and when I connect it it show "6" near to wifi icon